# Unit testing for iOS in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am planning to use MVC or VIPER architecture to use.
How do I make the unit testing?
How should the unit testing be done for different design patterns?
Should all the methods be tested or only non-private methods?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make the unit testing?

Xcode has a built in testing framework called XCTest you could use, alternatively there are multiple other testing libraries: Appium, Calabash, EarlGrey and much more.

> How should the unit testing be done for different design patterns?

Testing between different design patterns should be fairly similar if you've made your code well decoupled. Here are some tips: https://medium.com/practical-ios-development/the-anatomy-of-a-well-architected-ios-unit-test-a509d2be9ec0

> Should all the methods be tested or only non-private methods?

All public methods should be testable and more often than not should be pure functions.
A pure function is one in which given the same input will always produce the same output.